# Is it valid to model discrete numerical test scores as coming from a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, data-transformation, ordinal-data, discrete-data

I'm working with a sample of test scores which range from 0 to 100. These scores are generated from a set of 100 binary responses (0 or 1), so the higher the resulting sum, the better the performance.  The distribution of these scores is definitely not normal: it is highly skewed. I'm interested in carrying out a Box-Cox transformation to make this data more normal.

Since the data is very discrete, but ordinal, I'm considering doing a Kernel Density Estimation (which would model a continuous distribution), and apply the transformation on the resulting (continuous-valued) model.

Is this a valid approach? If not, I'd appreciate any pointers on modeling this sort of probability distribution.

Comment: It would help to know why you are modeling these data.  For some purposes a continuous approximation may be fine and for others it might not be a good idea.  I also find myself wondering just what a KDE would be estimating, because the distribution is inherently discrete anyway.

Comment: I'm using a KDE as a plugin to a Bayesian classifier for the moment, though I've used the Naive variant too. Regarding why I'm trying to model this distribution at all, it's basically an exploration to see if the data can be summarised succinctly: maybe even used for subsequent prediction without having to resort to Bayesian methods.